# Why did the man steal the protagonist's lump?

Tags: kobu-tori

In the 1929 anime Kobu Tori, The protagonist has his facial deformation taken away by the tengu for being good entertainment and a welcome guest.

When the antagonist follows in his footsteps, he goes to the tengu also to get rid of the lump on his own face.

[image: lumpy]

Kobu Tori is a silent film, so I wasn't able to translate the dialogue and I don't understand why does the antagonist steals the protagonist's lump

[image: No one steals from the tengu.]

Is it to return it to him? To sell it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengu#In_popular_folk_tales):

> An old man has a lump or tumor on his face. In the mountains he encounters a band of tengu making merry and joins their dancing. He pleases them so much that they want him to join them the next night, and offer a gift for him. In addition, they take the lump off his face, thinking that he will want it back and therefore have to join them the next night. An unpleasant neighbor, who also has a lump, hears of the old man's good fortune and attempts to repeat it, and steal the gift. The tengu, however, simply give him the first lump in addition to his own, because they are disgusted by his bad dancing, and because he tried to steal the gift.

The mean old man doesn't want to steal it, he wants to get rid of it like the protagonist did.

Comment: Oh so he stole a gift, not the lump. It all makes sense now :)